# Save the Kusto query result into a table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Save the Kusto query result into a temp table and then do a swap..

Answer (score 4):

you could look into using `.set-or-replace` (or a combination of `.set-or-append` and `.rename tables`)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query

Comment: you may want to explain why the answer provided doesn't solve your question. it's not clear from your latest comment (which seems to repeat your original question)

Comment: thanks. it's a little clearer, though `.set-or-replace` can create an entirely different table, and will only replace an existing table if you specify one. what about the other option provided in the answer - using `.set-or-append`?